# Scrape all of a website's listings, Exceeding the page limit

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-science

I am trying to scrape a food reviewing website similar to Yelp. I have done the part of scraping an individual page and obtain the information of a single restaurant. But I have encounter this problem where the website has over 900k listings, but page numbers only goes up to 60, showing at most 1200 listings. Even if I narrow the filters and go through each filter option, the listings under each filter would still be way over 1200. 
I am using requests and beautifulsoup for scraping. 
Any ideas for better or more efficient solution?

```py
def crawl_listing(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    #code for obtaining url of each listing on this page
    return (#dict of restaurant names and urls)

def crawl_detail(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    #code for getting all needed information about the restaurant

def main():
    full_list = []
    for page in range(30):
        address = f"https://www.example.com/list/{page}"
        full_list = full_list + crawl_listing(address)

    for restaurant in full_list:
        crawl_detail(restaurant['url'])
```

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the site (so you'll have to share what site you are actually scraping for more help), but most of the times what the site shows is not the only way to crawl it (maybe there could be more pagination that the limit shown in the site).

Another alternative is to check if the site has a `robots.txt` file which should be found in `https://www.example.com/robots.txt` from where you can see if there are some links you can't encounter with normal navigation.

The final and real recommendation is to use a web-crawling framework (I'd recommend [`scrapy`](http://scrapy.org/)) because if you are hitting the site too many times, you are going to be facing a lot of problems because of the speed of your requests. The framework can help you put some delays and retry automatically with certain rules, so it will make your life easier when you face with those common crawling challenges.

Comment: I'm encountering similar problem, where I'm trying to scrape  https://www.tesla.com/inventory/api/v1/inventory-results , but I hit a limit of maximum of 50  unique VINS per model per region. I did try the robots.txt but couldn't figure out anything helpful

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you already built out a pretty good scraper for the job; I’ve done something like this before where I searched for the class of the “next page” arrow link to teach my scraper when to go to the next portion (increment the next URL in the request with the next offset); this is one approach. A second approach would be to find an identifier and create a counter to count the total number of occurrences teaching your scraper where to stop and where additional reviews exist.

Ideally, the locating the next page tag is the best choice for knowing when you can offset and move forward. If your dealing with dynamic pages of unknown instances you should find a way to count and scrape until the end of the counter; another way of implementing this is by modifying the source by replacing the text in the HTML with a certain character to create your own place marks if that makes sense.